# QToolButton Space Between Text and Icon

Tags: css, qt, qtoolbutton

I have a QToolButton. I wanted text and icon to be on it. I set button style by setToolButtonStyle(Qt::ToolButtonTextBesideIcon).

But icon and text are so close to each other. Is there a method to give some space between icon and text by css?

Comment: Maybe try use  `Padding`: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp  in css ? I think you should `add padding-top: value px;`

Comment: You can make the icons wider, since they can be png with transparency. If you make them all same-width, they even align nicely vertically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. There is no such a property neither for `QToolButton` (nor for `QPushButton`). All the properties for these buttons are in the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtoolbutton).

One thing you can do is to create your own class inheriting from `QToolButton` and overriding the paintEvent(). In this function, you will manually place your icon.

This is the shortest solution, but if you're brave enough, there are longer paths, like creating your own button subclassing directly `QWidget` (but in this case, you will need to implement ALL its behavior).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just made the text starting with a little space. I mean, I changed the text "something" to "  something". This solved my problem for now. I hope I will not have to create/override something. :)

Comment: Be careful with that though, if you have several buttons, you will have to write blank spaces on every buttons ^^

Comment: Thanks again. I wrote a simple function for that.

Comment: You can also write a subclass for `QToolButton`  overriding its `setText` method to append the leading spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it although this is not the documented solution.
Just provide spaces in QPushButton text start. By Doing this, icon and text will automatically go far from each other.